# jquery variable scope "variable not defined"

Tags: jquery

```
labelSelect = "10";

  (function ($) {
    var db = {
                date_presets: {
                    'custom': {
                        title: labelSelect,
                    },
                }
            };
  })(jQuery);
```

I am getting the error `ReferenceError: labelSelect is not defined`

Comment: please declare your variables. But your bug is elsewhere. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please dont tell him guys :) it is nice if he got this one right.

Comment: @Desperado got answer.                                                                         no any problem in this code. only matter of time loading different script files

Comment: @Raj that's good. It's fulfilling to fix an issue :D goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

no any problem in this code.
only matter of time loading different script files